# How to mock a void method with Functional Interface/lambda param?

Tags: java, mockito

How do I mock a lambda expression that is passed as a param into a void method call?

I have the following class structure that I need to test, but I can't even instantiate it due to it's constructor.

Is there a way to mock the method call `someManager.doSomething`?
Or a way to mock `item.isDoItemSave`?

I can't figure it out and `SomeClass.setDoSave` throws a null pointer on the return call(`SomeClass line 18`) , since `doSave` is null.

Class I want to instantiate:

```java
public SomeClass() {

    private Boolean doSave;
    private SomeManager someManager;
    private SaveAction action;    

    public SomeClass(SomeManager someManager) {
        this.someManager = someManager;
        action = setDoSave() ? SAVE : null;
    } 

    private boolean setDoSave() {
        if(doSave == null) {
            someManager.doSomething(item -> {
                doSave = item.isDoItemSave();
            });
        }
        return doSave;
    }

}
```

SomeManager.doSomething is void:

```
public void doSomething(ItemUpdate update){
   Item item = new Item();
   update.update(item);
}
```

ItemUpdate is a functional interface:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ItemUpdate {
    void update(Item item);
}
```

I cannot refactor this constructor, who knows what will happen, the code is extremely coupled. 
I just want to be able to instantiate `SomeClass`.

My test class looks like this, naturally tests fail in the `@BeforeEach` on `SomeClass` constructor call:

```
class SomeClassTest {

    private SomeClass someClass;

    @Mock
    private SomeManager someManagerMock;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        this.someClass = new SomeClass(someManagerMock);
    }

    @Test
    void someClassTest() {
        someClass.anyOtherMethod();
    }

}
```

Comment: can u please specify more details like, existing test case that you have written and line number where NullPointerException occurs

Comment: @AmitPatil please read my question, I can't even instantiate this class. There is no test case. I have added my test class and clarified where the null pointer is thrown.

Comment: @curiosa I have added the code of my test class.  I am struggling to figure out how to mock this void method, that automagically via lambda return a value.

Comment: What is `Item` and what does `item.isDoItemSave()` do?

Comment: @MaxVollmer Item is just a pojo. ```item.isDoItemSave()``` as naming convention implies returns the boolean value of field doItemSave inside Item.

Comment: @curiosa I know, I did that but it's still not going to execute ```doSave = item.isDoItemSave();``` which in turn will result in the same npe.

Comment: @MaxVollmer This is actual code, I just had to rename things. Question is, given this method call structure, what is a possible way of mocking it?

Comment: @IgorFlakiewicz research `doAnswer-when` with mockito and mocking void members

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick glance at the documentation shows the following example that I have applied to your situation

```
@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    //configure the mock
    // Java 8 - style 2 - assuming static import of AdditionalAnswers
    doAnswer(answerVoid(ItemUpdate update) -> {
        Item item = new Item();
        //...populate item as needed

        update.update(item);
    })
    .when(someManagerMock).doSomething(any(ItemUpdate.class));

    this.someClass = new SomeClass(someManagerMock);
}
```

Reference [Java 8 Custom Answer Support](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.1.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#Java_8_Custom_Answers)

Note that I have not tested this. I am going based on what was shown in the docs.

Comment: That's awesome, many thanks. I read your earlier comment and implemented exactly that, just before I saw  your answer. Thank you again.

I guess I must train my google foo if I couldn't find this doc on my own. :)

Answer (score 1):

For now I have made changes so SomeClass at least instantiates.
Lesson learned, watch your assignments from Boolean to boolean.

```java
    private boolean setDoSave() {
        if(doSave == null) {
            someManager.doSomething(item -> {
                doSave = item.isDoItemSave();
            });
        }

        return doSave != null ? doSave : false;
    }
```

I'm leaving this question open hoping someone with better knowledge of Mocking frameworks can provide a way of mocking this case.

Answer (score -1):

> I can't figure it out and SomeClass.setDoSave throws a null pointer,
>   since doSave is null.

`SomeClass.setDoSave` throws NPE since instance variable `someManager` is `null`.

Try adding `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` to your test class.

Comment: That is not true, 1st that annotation is not required with the way my test is structured. 2nd I know exactly where the npe is coming from and I need to mock doSave = item.isDoItemSave(); to return a boolean value. I just don't know how to do that.